# Are my memory leaks caused by circular referencing?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, doubly-linked-list

I'm creating a doubly linked list in C++. When adding to the front of the list I receive the following **memory leak**:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{193} normal block at 0x000001F7A1EC01B0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: < 0              > A0 30 EB A1 F7 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{192} normal block at 0x000001F7A1EB3090, 96 bytes long.
 Data: < [J             > D0 5B 4A AE F7 7F 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{149} normal block at 0x000001F7A1EBF9E0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <   #            > D8 F7 15 23 E4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

**Here is my code:**

```
struct Node {
    bool exists = false;
    int element;
    shared_ptr<node> prevNode = nullptr;
    shared_ptr<node> nextNode = nullptr;
};

class DLL {
public:
    shared_ptr<Node> frontNode = make_shared<Node>();
    shared_ptr<Node> backNode = make_shared<Node>();
    void frontAdd(int x);
}

void DLL::frontAdd(int x) {
    shared_ptr<Node> tempNode = make_shared<Node>();
    tempNode->exists = true;
    tempNode->element = x;
    tempNode->prevNode = nullptr;

    if (frontNode->exists) {
        tempNode->nextNode = frontNode;
        frontNode->prevNode = tempNode;
    }
    else {
        backNode = tempNode;
    }

    frontNode = tempNode;
};
```

I have tried using unique pointers and weak pointers but I'm unfamiliar with weak pointers and as a beginner I've found it very hard integrating them with this project.
I have tried removing make_shared on the frontNode and the tempNode and instead creating them without make_shared but in both instances this returns a write access violation saying "returned nullptr". In the autos tempNode is empty so this makes sense.

Since the shared_ptr goes out of scope I expected all ownership to be lost and memory leaks to be non-existent, but I guess because of the "make_shared" it was added to the heap and so can't be removed from memory so easily?

Comment: [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is reference-counted so yes, you'd normally expect cycles like this to cause a leak. That's one of the reasons for [`weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) to exist in the first place. Do you understand what happens when your DLL object is destroyed, and what state all the shared pointers are in?

Comment: Also not sure why you need the 'exists' flag - you can just test if the frontNode shared pointer is set or not.

Comment: If it's the only pointer in the list prevNode and nextNode will be nullptr's, regardless of whether it exists or not, so it's necessary for the first creation at least

Comment: @Useless The reason for `weak_ptr` is **not** to "break cycles". In fact cycle of ownership just cannot exist, by definition. A cycle is a bug.

Comment: Do you want std container semantics? Like `std::list`? It means that the owners of every element is the container and iterators are invalidated when the container is destructed, cleared, and whenever the elements referred to by the iterators are removed.

Comment: @curiousguy - I refer you to the third paragraph of the `weak_ptr` doc I linked. One of the purposes of `weak_ptr` is **explicitly** to break ownership cycles, which not only **can** exist but actually do in this code.

Comment: @Useless You can't "fix by divisions by zero" by just changing any 0 to an 1; a value is 0 for some reason and you need to fix the problem (the need to solve the equation `x*0 = y` at all). The notion that "cycle of ownership" even exists is patently absurd: "cycle of ownership" implies that an object wants to "own itself" which is to say there is a bug. And yes it can "exist in code" just like division by zero can exist in code. Solving a problem involving an insolvable equation means changing the approach completely so the solution is well defined. You can define `div(x,0)=1` if you like.

Comment: Since the code in the question as asked visibly has a cycle in the node ownership, and the cppreference page for weak_ptr explicitly mentions breaking such cycles, you might at least consider that this is a class of bug that genuinely exists, people have genuinely experienced, and that weak_ptr is one possible way of solving this bug. I don't see how the existence of this well-attested issue can reasonably be considered "absurd" even if you consider it a bug rather than a design wrinkle. It's perfectly normal for this issue to arise (and be addressed) in garbage collectors, for example.

Comment: @Useless You apparently missed my point: cycle ownership is nonsensical. No tool can solve the bug because it's nonsensical. "_weak_ptr explicitly mentions breaking such cycles_" Yep, it's explicit written nonsense. "_weak_ptr is one possible way of solving this bug._" How can is "solve" a "bug"? `weak_ptr` doesn't express ownership. You might as well say that removing one smart owner deletes the cycle. It does, but the program is broken, because of a missing link. "_It's perfectly normal for this issue to arise (and be addressed) in garbage collectors,_" They don't, they can't.

Comment: This comment chain is really getting out of hand. If I create two objects, each containing a shared ptr "owning" the other, I have a cycle. That's not nonsense, it's a simple fact. Now, you might think the decision to do that is nonsensical (and you'd often, but not always, be right), but throwing around unqualified claims of "nonsense" is unhelpful and inaccurate. I can't tell whether you believe this situation _can not_ arise (which would be incorrect), or simply _should not_ arise (which is generally true, but unhelpful when it clearly has arisen), or you have some other issue.

Comment: @Useless "_but throwing around unqualified claims of "nonsense" is unhelpful and inaccurate_" 1) *Nonsense* here **refers to the design** where someone decided that A owns B and at the same time B owns A. It does *not* refer to the real observation that such nonsensical code gets written sometimes. (It's absurd to suppose that a criticism of some buggy code is a criticism of the observation that such buggy code exists in the real world.)

Comment: 2) The notion that ownership can be cyclic is absurd, just like the notion you can find the one `x` such that `x*0 = a`. I not only call "absurd" the idea that a design with cycles of ownership is a meaningful but I also call "nonsensical" the idea that a broken design (because of a cycle) can be fixed by sacrificing a strong link in a cycle and replacing the sacrificed link with a weak reference. **This isn't even C++ specific**: if your design calls for strong ref, it needs the strong ref. **Just because the design is nonsensical doesn't mean you have the right to break it.**

Comment: Remove the needed parts in machine that doesn't work won't make it work. Removing a strong link even in a broken design will make it more broken, unless there was never a need for a strong link. A `weak_ptr` obviously isn't a drop in replacement for `shared_ptr`, and it inherently can't provide the same semantics. (If it could, a cycle of `shared_ptr` would be fine.)

Comment: 3) "_and the cppreference page for weak_ptr explicitly mentions breaking such cycles,_" Well **extremely bad programming advice have always existed**. Consider the advice to just avoid goto. In any case. Even for early exit of a loop. Even for error handling. Even at the cost of more state variables, or changing the loop counter to an arbitrary value that causes immediate exit. Even at the cost of ridiculously large nesting level and many trivial if/then/else. And that advice was even given as an absolute in languages with exception where single exit isn't a thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186432/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-useless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a circular dependency on all your nodes. Each node points to the next one and to the previous, so multiple circular dependencies for each node, outside head and tail.

You can fix this by using a `weak_ptr` for the previous link, for instance. This will incur some performance hit, as you need to get a new shared pointer fromt he weak pointer to access the previous nodes.

Comment: Why would you make the previous link a weak link?

Comment: It's one or the other. But usually, even with a bidirectional iterator, we mainly use forward, not backward, so the cost would only happen in that case, when using reverse iterators or --.

Comment: What happens if the referent is gone? When is -- allowed to fail?

Comment: In that case, when you try to get a shared_ptr out of the weak_ptr, it will fail.

Comment: It will fail, then what? Is that expected? Is that conforming to the Bidi Iterator concept?

Comment: Well, it will, undefined behavior if you try to get an access to an invalid iterator.

Comment: 1) Which iterator is invalid? 2) At which point did it became invalid?

Comment: If the iterator is not updated when the previous one is deleted, then it's a bug. Nothing more to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186318/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-matthieu-brucher).

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your circular reference is the cause. shared_ptr isn't that smart, and simply counts the number of references, and the back pointer keeps the count non-zero.

You need to use either raw pointers or weak_ptr<> for anything that could be considered a "back" pointer, either from a subordinate child object, or where you have a 2-way list.

`weak_ptr<>` has an operational cost, but has the advantage that the child object can act safely with little coding effort.

Comment: "_child object can act safely_" but it needs to able to be able to handle properly the case where the referent is gone

Comment: For anyone who can't be bothered to read the chat thread under the other answer: this comment is mistaken and both answers are fine. The shared pointers are just an implementation detail of the list (if a pretty questionable one), and nothing outside the list affects node lifetimes.

Comment: @curiousguy yes, code does have to handle weak_ptr failure, but as it has already tried to "open" the weak_ptr, this is "easy" to do safely, and "hard" to do badly. I don't feel the need to explain how to write safe code in this case, as it is obvious from the documentation of weak_ptr. Given a raw pointer, there is no guarantee of lifetime, and it often can't be used "safely" even with a lot of design effort.

Comment: @GemTaylor With all the "smart" "pointers" in the world, all you can do at the end of the day is get a "raw pointer": a real C++ pointer. Calling a member function is done via `this`, not a "smart pointer". So at some point you need to trust the programmers to use the tools properly. Or drop C++ and use a "safe" language (Java, O'Caml...).